# Normalizing a set of positive numbers $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ under given conditions

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be $n(>1)$ strictly positive numbers. I want to map them to numbers $y_1,\cdots, y_n$ such that $y_j = y_j(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ (except the trivial constant function) such that $$\sum_{j=1}^n y_j=m,\ 0\le y_j\le 1,\ \forall j=1,\cdots, n.$$ Here I am assuming that $1\le m\le n$, and $m$ need not be an integer.

Of course, if $m=n$, we must have $y_j=x_j=1,\ \forall 1\le j\le n$. So the more interesting case is $m<n$.

If $m=1$, then we can just use $$y_j=\frac{x_j}{\sum_{i}x_i},\ j=1,\cdots,n.$$

But in the general case, I wonder if there is always a set of (nontrivial non-constant) functions that satisfy these conditions. Any ideas or references?

Comment: The question needs to be made more specific somehow. For example, the functions $y_j = \frac{m}{n}$ work, but I doubt that's what you're really looking for.

Comment: The most obvious thing to try that looks like what you want is $y_j = \frac{mx_j}{\sum_i x_i}$, but there is no guarantee that $0 \leq y_j \leq 1$ in this case.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins, the suggestion $y_j=\frac{mx_j}{\sum_i x_i}$ is the first thing that comes to mind, but it might violate the second condition. Therefore the question.